# Selenium Multiple Webdriver Scripts

Tags: java, selenium

I am implementing my selenium scripts by using webdriver and i am using TestNG framework. I want to run multiple Scripts at a time by using Command line. Please guide me how to run multiple scripts on command line. My Integrated Dev Env is Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Create a testng.xml containing multiple scripts that you want to execute and follow the instructions documented [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) to run them from command line.